# Dragging the AIR application window around the screen

Tags: apache-flex, events

I have an AIR application. It should be moved around the screen with the mouse. In order to achieve this I use the event:

```
this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown, true,-2);
```

It should be activated with the lowest priority compared to inserted elements for example those that should be scrolled, clicked, etc.

I tried the solution shown below with the event priority set to -1 because there might happen 2 different events and my moving application event should be the last one to be serviced or shouldn't be serviced at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="200" 
                       height="200"
                       applicationComplete="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.Window;
            import mx.events.ScrollEvent;

            private function init():void {
                this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown, true,-2);   
            }

            private function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
                trace("clicked on stage "+event.currentTarget.toString());
                if(event.currentTarget == stage){
                    trace("catched stage target");
                    this.nativeWindow.startMove();
                    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                }

            }
            function scrolledCanvasHandler(event:ScrollEvent){
                trace("clicked on canvas "+event.currentTarget.toString());
                event.stopPropagation();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:Canvas x="29" y="34" width="80%" height="80%" backgroundColor="#343434" scroll="scrolledCanvasHandler(event)">
        <mx:Label x="25" y="77" text="moving window, moving window"
                  fontSize="18" color="#FFFFFF" fontWeight="bold"/>

    </mx:Canvas>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

As you will notice the

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

doesn't work.

Perhaps my solution isn't the best suited to achieve this. Are there better solutions?

Chris

Comment: I meant dragging the AIR application window over the screen using the mouse. When it is no chrome application (control strip is not present then) clicking in the application border should be the starting point for dragging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's what i did in an app of mine:

```
<s:HGroup id="appTitleBar" 
  width="100%" height="35" 
  styleName="titleBar" 
  mouseDown="nativeWindow.startMove();" 
  doubleClickEnabled="true" 
  doubleClick="nativeWindow.minimize();"  
  contentBackgroundColor="#313131"/>
```

click (+drag) on this HGroup will drag the window. duobleclick will minimize it.

**edit**
don't make your whole app draggable this will only confuse the user.
and btw priority should be positive not negative - but also don't mess with this. not expected behavior for anyone.